# python pandas\numpy encode unique by integers

Tags: python, pandas, integer, unique, categorical-data

Say I have `x=["apple","orange","orange","apple","pear"]` I would like to have a categorical representation with integers e.g. `y=[1,2,2,1,3]`. What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: What do the integers represent?

Comment: Presumably you checked the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)?

Comment: If you're working with `numpy` you can simply `np.unique(["apple","orange","orange","apple","pear"], return_inverse=True)[1]`, without turning to pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.factorize`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir7Iq5pKnKAhXJfywKHYXzDWgQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.factorize.html&usg=AFQjCNGj_rPJkPRzi1iP3sFOK0BWVf8ZZg&bvm=bv.111677986,d.bGQ) and use field 0 for that:

```
In [465]: pd.factorize(x)
Out[465]: (array([0, 1, 1, 0, 2]), array(['apple', 'orange', 'pear'], dtype=object))

In [466]: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1
Out[466]: array([1, 2, 2, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd

x=["apple","orange","orange","apple","pear"]
s = pd.Series(x)

print s

0     apple
1    orange
2    orange
3     apple
4      pear

print pd.Categorical(s).codes

[0 1 1 0 2]
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd

x=["apple","orange","orange","apple","pear"]

print pd.Categorical(x).codes

#[0 1 1 0 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

With Pandas: `x.astype('category').cat.codes`